# No read with delegate multithread fix and no form pops up

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, serial-port

I need to update an windows form label with a string received from the serial port. I've got two problems with the code I made already.

Because the reading of the serial port needs another thread I use a delegate method to update the label text.

The first problem is that the form window wont open when I start the program (it does open when I don't call `initSerialPort()` in `Form1_Load()`).

The second problem is that it seems like it doesn't reach `Debug.Write(message)` when I call `_self.SetText(message)` in `Read()`. When I comment out `_self.SetText(message)` it does log the message but also doesn't open the form window because `initSerialPort()` is called in `Form1_Load()`

I'm kind of an noob with C#, just so you know ;)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private static SerialPort _serialPort;
        private static Boolean _continue;
        private static StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        private static Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);
        private static Form1 _self;
        private static Label _lbl;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _self = this;

            _lbl = label1;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initSerialPort();
        }

        public void setMessage(string mes)
        {
            label1.Text = mes;
        }

        private static void initSerialPort()
        {
            // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
            _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            // Set the read/write timeouts
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            _serialPort.Open();
            _continue = true;
            readThread.Start();

            readThread.Join();
            _serialPort.Close();
            _serialPort = null;
        }

        public static void Read()
        {
            Debug.Write("testread");
            while (_continue)
            {

                try
                {
                    String message = _serialPort.ReadLine();

                    _self.SetText(message);

                    Debug.Write(message);


                }
                catch (TimeoutException) { }

            }
        }

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.label1.Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look at using the DataReceived event instead of running your own thread and using BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `Join` to the new thread you create. That is going to block the thread until your `Read` method completes, which means it never completes.